# Is this sentence correct? "Adele says new album will explain her divorce to her young son."

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, modifiers

So there's this debate ongoing on one post that this phrase is incorrect. People are getting confused and wondering how can Adele take a divorce from her own son. The sentence is:

> Adele says new album will *explain her divorce to her young son.*

Is the above sentence correct? I always thought a divorce was taken *from* someone and not *to* someone.

For context, the sentence is being used a headline caption for an image.

Comment: No reader other than AI will read *divorce to her son* and crave *divorce from her son*. Ever. Although, if the reader is drawn in to read the article and solve the confusion, the headline did its job well.

Answer (score 3):

In normal writing, we'd add a 'her' between the 'says' and the 'new,' but this is headlinese so it's okay. (Adele says *her* new album will...)

But otherwise, it's correct. ***Divorce* is a noun here, not a verb; the verb is *to explain***, so your confusion about *to*/*from* isn't quite relevant here. In this sort of sentence, we use verbs such as *explain*, *report*, *describe*, etc. with *to*:

- I *reported* the information *to* her.
- I  *described* the picture *to* him.
- It *explained* the technicalities *to* its readers.

In your headline,

> Adele says [her] new album will explain her divorce to her young son.

The album will *explain* the divorce *to* her son.

---

As a side note:

We'd be dealing with ambiguity if we had a sentence like '*Adele says her new album will explain her marriage to her young son*', in which we'd be unsure as to whether it's   '*Adele says her new album will explain [her marriage to her young son]*' or '*Adele says her new album will explain [her marriage] to her young son*'.

Comment: This is exactly what i thought. There's one guy who's going on this tirade about it being a misplaced modifier